# Read CSV Into Memory

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have a submit button that opens a link to a CSV file.  The file currently downloads to the local disk.  I need to display the contents of the CSV on the page (possibly in a label) without downloading the CSV to the disk.  Is this possible?

```
protected void submit(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    System.Diagnostics.Process.Start(
        "http://download.finance.yahoo.com/d/quotes.csv?s=YHOO+GOOG+MSFT&f=sl1d1t1c1hgvbap2");           
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Simplest solution is to use `WebClient.DownloadString("http://server/file.csv")` method. [MSDN reference](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/system.net.webclient.downloadstring%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

Comment: You might also be interested in DownloadStringAsync, its in the link @Knagis supplied.  This method won't block the UI thread while the data is being obtained.

Comment: since he's using ASP.NET there is no UI thread. it might be possible to use async there but that requires much more additional plumbing.